# App looking for an invalid dynamic library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, dynamic-linking

[alt text http://img63.imageshack.us/img63/5726/screenshot20100125at124.png](http://img63.imageshack.us/img63/5726/screenshot20100125at124.png)

I keep getting multiple error windows for an app i'm developing asking for **._libpal_bullet.dll** when it should really be just **libpal_bullet.dll**. The weird thing is after I get all the error messages, the app runs anyway using the correct dlls that exist in the same directory.

How can i get rid of these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Extrakun, you indirectly helped me figure this one out.

I guess this happens when you copy code between OSes.

The problem was that there were duplicate files of these library names in the build folder. They were metadata files from OS X, which must have come over to the Windows side when I copied the folder to Windows. It's strange that they would be attempted to be executed even though they have different names to the proper DLLs.

Anyway deleting the files (they were hidden!) solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Dependencies Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/) to step through the code to see who is invoking the call to the DLL. Maybe you have the ._libpal_bullet.dll included in your release configuration.